# Escaping backslash from Linkformatter to javascript function | SlickGrid

Tags: javascript, jsp, slickgrid

Hi i am using slickgrid formatter.i am getting the value correct in grid.when using formatter to javascript function i m missing '\'..how can i get the data with '\'
Here goes my code

```
var linkFormatter = function ( row, cell, value, columnDef, dataContext ) {
return '<a href="javascript:test(\'' + dataContext['data'] + '\');" class="listLink">'  + value + '</a>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var linkFormatter = function ( row, cell, value, columnDef, dataContext ) {
   return '<a href="javascript:test(\\'' + dataContext['data'] + '\\');" class="listLink">'  + value + '</a>';
}
```

Then-again, I always use something like this:

```
var linkFormatter = function ( row, cell, value, columnDef, dataContext ) {
   return '<a href="#" data="'+dataContext['data']+'" class="listLink">'  + value + '</a>';
}

...

$("a.listLink").click(function(){
   var data = $(this).attr("data");
   ...
   return false;
});
```

Comment: when using single quotes,its not displayed..what u say abt that..as i m new it wil be very simple questions..let me know whether there is any option in this slickgrid to accept any special characters...thanks in adv..!!!